# Will Allah still forgive me? Please answer!

Tags: allah, sin, forgiveness

I am 13 years old, and a girl.

I used to masturbate, I repented and I really regret doing those things. Ever since I quit masturbating, I felt a little better but I was still worried about the consequences.

I started to ejaculate almost everyday and since ejaculation is haram, I became so afraid, I started crying because I couldn't control my ejaculation. Yesterday, I closed my eyes and said 'Allah please help me stop ejaculating. I want to be a good muslim. Ameen'

But it didn't work.

I keep ejaculating out of nowhere, even though I haven't masturbated. I feel like Allah will never accept my wudu, ghusl, dua, and prayer because I feel like my ejaculation is going to interrupt.

Is it normal to be ejaculating like this? Will it ever end? I don't want to go to hell, please help!

Answer (score 0):

Allah will forgive you! Going through ejaculation is normal after masturbation. It's probably just premature ejaculation but it will go away in a few months!

Allah is merciful and forgives ALL sins!
Keep your head up high and keep believing!

Try doing other things that help erase your mind from your anxiety and thoughts such as gaming, exercising, or anything else that can easily distract you.
Avoid being alone and make sure you're always in company. Whether it is your family, or friends.

Don't EVER think that Allah will never be able to forgive you. Remember, that Allah had once told Adam that he'd forgive his sins, even if the amount was to reach the heavens!

Allah loves to forgive, and he is pleased to see that you are seeking for help since you greatly regret what you have done. Keep doing good deeds, try and recite the Quran, and try learning duas to help resist your urge and temptation.

Answer (score 0):

You are 13 years old, which means you're a teenager whose hormones are very strong.

It's completely normal for you to ejaculate, since your body is accomodated to sexual stimulation. Now that you stopped sexually stimulating your body, it starts to ejaculate due to the high concentration of sexual hormones. *Don't worry continue like this and you won't ejaculate after some time (your libido will be lower).*

**Ejaculation is NOT haram.** You don't do it on purpose. Allah is Al-Bari' which means he is innocent when he judges. If he judges you on something you didn't do on purpose/you can't control, then how is he innocent ? Allah **will not punish you if you can't control ejaculation.**

You repented, so everything concerning your repent is forgiven because Allah is al-Ghafur ar-Raheem which means He is the forgiver, the compassionate.

Allah says "La tad3aw anfousakoum li tahlouka" in the Quran which basically means "don't push yourself too much". So do your effort and try to do wudu, Allah will accept your wudu and your salah if you don't ejaculate. Allah is Al-Mujib so he will always respond to your dua if your heart is concentrated during your dua.

Conclusion:
**EJACULATION IS NOT HARAM AND ALLAH WILL NOT PUNISH YOU IF YOU CAN'T CONTROL YOURSELF. YOUR SINS ARE FORGIVEN IF YOU REPENT.**